# Given a set $A$ and a function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$, when is the image $f(A)$ a half space?

Tags: functions, proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $A$ be an arbitrary set with arbitrary element $a\in A$, and let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be an $n$-dimensional real-valued function with image $f(A)\equiv\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n:f(a)=\mathbf{x}\text{ for some }a\in A\}$. I am trying to find a set of sufficient (and ideally also necessary) conditions on the set $A$ and the function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^n$ for the image $f(A)$ to be the half-space defined by $f(A)=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n:\sum_{i\leq n}x_i\leq\kappa\text{ for some }\kappa\in\mathbb{R}\}$. **Can anybody please help me find which are these sufficient (and necessary) conditions?**

My attempt at answering this question led me to conclude (so far) that $A$ must be a convex and infinite set. Further, let $f_i:A\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:A\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f_i(a)=x_i$ and $g(a)=\sum_{i\leq n}f_i(a)$. I think that $g:A\to\mathbb{R}$ must be bounded above by $\kappa$ (i.e., $\exists\kappa\in\mathbb{R}:g(a)\leq\kappa$ for all $a\in A$) and must also be unbounded below ($\nexists \kappa'\in\mathbb{R}:g(a)\geq\kappa'\forall a\in A$). I think that the conditions defined in this paragraph are necessary but not sufficient for the equality $f(A)=\{\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n:\sum_{i\leq n}x_i\leq\kappa\text{ for some }\kappa\in\mathbb{R}\}$ to hold true. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you all very much in advanced.

Comment: Unless you want $f$ to satisfy some sort of regularity like continuity the answer is that a function $f$ exists if and only if $A$ has cardinality greater than or equal to that of the continuum.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I quite didn’t follow your argument. Could you please help me further by expanding it a bit?

Comment: Is $f$ what, linear, continuous, differentiable? I mean, as stated, this is a horribly difficult trivial question.